# How can i add dynamically Images in a Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, imageview, displayobject

im coding an android app for a board game. The user can choose in the main activity how many dices he want to roll(1 up to 3).

I would like to use only one activity to display the result of the dices as images. The user can go back to the main activity and choose a other amount of dices.

My problem is, how can i dynamically add the needed imageviews for the result images into the second activity where i want to display the results of the choosen amount of dices?

Comment: Here you cann see what i want to do [link](http://imgur.com/a/2YizR#0). On the main activity are imagebuttons. The user decide how many dices he want and which color. After that i want to display the dices in the second Actity. But always in another Layout as shown in the images.

Comment: Okay, im trying this. 
'GridLayout layout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layoutfordices);
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   
  imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(this);
  imageViewArray[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.bd2);
  layout.addView(imageViewArray[i]);
  }
  '

do i have to make if clauses for layout params like if dices = diceamount make only 2 imageviews in a row. sth like that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `ImageView` object, set its properties, and then add it to an existing layout. Here is the most basic form, but you will need to add `LayoutParams` as well to get the desired location.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
iv.setImageResource(R.id.myimage);
someView.add(id);
```

See the [ImageView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) for more usage details.